# Why do I get these messages when I'm trying to add GNOME themes?

Tags: gnome, themes

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15763): WARNING **: 01:18:54.678: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15763): WARNING **: 01:18:54.679: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 01:18:54.850: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Nautilus-Share-Message: 01:19:23.481: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Ubuntu version: 20.04.1 LTS
GNOME version: 3.36.3

I'm installing themes from [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/).

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Where do the themes come from?  How are you installing them?  Currently your question is unclear, and without an actual question (some browser setups don't show the heading when viewing your question which is nothing but a paste without any question or explanation)

Comment: Why is there reference to /root/ ; what OS are you using?  That's rather insecure & bad practice (desktop should not be run or have access to /root/)

Comment: ubuntu 20.04.1 lts gnome version 3.36.3

Comment: installing from gnome-look